# Styles missing after CollectStatic

Tags: css, django, django-cms, django-1.8, collectstatic

So...It's the first time I have to edit a Django project.

I edited some css and after updating my files in server I did:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

The problem is that now I have lost all the styles in the website. When inspecting I find there are some error about not finding some Cache Files (??)

```
GET http://example.com/es/site-static/CACHE/css/dc29b2f71452.css/ 404 (Not Found)
```

Fortunately, this was in my dev server but I had to perform changes in prod but I can't take the risk with this problem. Is there a way to revert back changes btw?

anyone's willing to help a Django noob?

EDIT: File in question (dc29b2f71452.css) exists so I checked the file permissions and modified them to 777 but it seems that's not the problem. Any idea?

Comment: Don't post images of errors, but the actual code. Difficult to read as it is, it's a 404 error. Did you maybe change the names of your css files and didn't update the template?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. What I want to tell with that image is that it can't find a css file in "site-static/CACHE". That is what I find weird. Which code do you need to see exactly?